# Spring JDBC - BeanPropertyRowMapper with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-jdbc

***Overview:***
The application deals with basic CRUD functionality for User information.

***Issue:***
While reading user details from the pre-populated H2 database, I am facing issues while using `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.
The mapper is not able to initialize the User instance as it is not able to use the default constructer of the data class.

***Data Class:***

[image]

***Repository:***

[image]

***Error:***

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No argument provided for a required parameter: parameter #0 id of fun <init>(kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String, java.util.Date): org.chrysalis.userservice.model.User
```

Providing a specific rowmapper solves the issue, but I am confused why `BeanPropertyRowMapper` is not able to create the response.

[image]
I am also wondering if this issue is just specific to the Java reflection and if this would be the same for other mapping utilities in spring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the update to `SpringFramework 5.3`/`SpringBoot 2.4`, mapping by constructor call is now supported by the `DataClassRowMapper`.

https://spring.pleiades.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/DataClassRowMapper.html

I consider `KRowMapper` to have an advantage in terms of functionality, but if you don't feel the pain of using an external library, I recommend using `DataClassRowMapper`.

---

*The following is an old answer.*

Basically, the same thing happens with other tools.

The Java reflection tools initialize the instance with a no-arg constructor and then a setter to initialize the field.
On the other hand, Kotlin's data class has no no-arg constructor and no setter (you can confirm this by decompiling).

So you need to define the field as a var and prepare the no-arg constructor or use Kotlin no-arg plugin (which breaks the null safety).

I also had trouble with the same situation, so I created a tool based on Kotlin reflection.
Please use it if you like.
https://github.com/ProjectMapK/KRowMapper